# Is it bad practice to verify arguments passed to a function?

Tags: javascript, functions, parameters, type-casting

I find myself writing a lot of functions whereby the first few lines "verify" the arguments, that is, they typecast, check falseness, range, etc. before doing any work. The main reasoning for this is to prevent idiots—human or otherwise—from passing invalid or illogical arguments to the function. An example in JS would be this:

```
function mix(red, grn, blu, anotherColor) {
  // typecast, falseness/presence
  this.red = +red || 0
  this.grn = +red || 0
  this.blu = +red || 0

  // args must be within [0, 255]
  this.red = Math.max(0, Math.min(red, 255))
  this.grn = Math.max(0, Math.min(grn, 255))
  this.blu = Math.max(0, Math.min(blu, 255))

  // if anotherColor is falsy/undefined
  anotherColor = anotherColor || {red:0, grn:0, blu:0}

  // do the actual work here
}
```

Another example is when a recursive function calls itself.

```
function menulist(pages, depth) {
  // do some stuff

  // when done, recurse
  if (depth > 0) {
    // verify pages.sub exists
    pages.sub = pages.sub || []

    return menulist(pages.sub, depth-1)
  }
}
```

On the other hand I've heard the opinion that this "verification" shouldn't be done within the function itself, rather, it should be delegated to some other piece of the software. In other words, the function should be "pure" and minimal, assuming the arguments passed will be correct. (If this is the case, where should the verification process be delegated?)

Which opinion is considered **best practice** in the Javascript community, and/or in the programming community as a whole?

Comment: I can't think of anything I would say here that isn't in the accepted answer on gnat's question, and I'm pretty sure there's nothing unique to Javascript that would change it, so I'm thinking duplicate.

Comment: I agree that this question is a duplicate. The linked question is even more general than this one, since it does not restrict t JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done isn't validation. You've pretty much just said "Guess what the user wanted". Validating it would throw an error if it was outside the range, not randomly coerce it to inside the range.

It's perfectly fine for a function to validate its arguments. It's also fine to do what you've done, which is to effectively default them. But those two things are *not* the same.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: You write a spec what your function does. Step 2: You implement it according to the spec.

Your spec may say that inappropriate arguments lead to undefined behaviour, or lead to an error being reported, or get fixed. Each is fine. Just write a spec and follow it.

Comment: This answer really doesn't have any useful information in it.